# How to determine style library in sharepoint libaries list using client object model

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am writing SharePoint client app on C# using client object model for SharePoint 2013. In my app I need to distinct some site service document libraries.
Actually I am looking for localization independent way to determine that a document library is "Style Libary".
I cannot use library's title as I am afraid that title is different in different languages of SharePoint site.
Is there any language independent way to determine this library?